# Поставить на весь экран картинку в качестве background`a

Tags: css

Написал в body таким образом:

`body {
   font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   background: url(/img/339990526.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: top;
   background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size:cover;
   -webkit-background-size:cover;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   color: #000;
}`

Но ничего не получается, в Гугл Хроме выводиться на весь экран, а вот в других браузерах нет, просто посредине картинка. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: В Мозиле и Гугл Хроме, прошу прощение, работает, а вот в опере нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть другой способ 
Вставить картинку

```
 <body>
    <img src="" >
    </body>
    img{width:100%;height:100%;
    z-index:0;position:absolute}
```

Answer (score 2):

так, эм...как так взять и забить на Oper'y? и, кстати, Opera поддерживает данное свойство. к тому же в поддержке `CSS3` она опережает и IE9 и Safari, а лисе всего 2% сдает. ну это так...

По поводу картинки на бэкграунде - это извечная проблема. и есть ли смысл вообще это делать?) тут либо картинка, либо повторите теоретическую часть по [свойству -o-background-size](http://htmlbook.ru/css/-o-background-size)

**ВАЖНО!!!!**
обнаружился баг Opera, связанный именно со свойством `-o-background-size: cover`. Читаем [подробнее о проблеме background-size](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1300942)

Comment: Вот, то о чем я говорю ниже. В опере куча багов.

Answer (score -3):

А разрешение картинки какое? Скорее всего опера не понимает -o-background-size и background-size и сама картинка имеет маленькое разрешение. Увеличьте разрешение картинки в фотошопе например. По поводу оперы, забейте на нее. Она не входит в число хороших браузеров.

Comment: `Opera` не входит в число хороших браузеров? Что, простите? По статистике `LiveInternet` в России за последние два месяца, браузеры на движке `Opera` (имеется ввиду сам браузер и его мобильная версия) суммарно охватывают большее кол-во пользователей, чем все браузеры на движке `Chromium` (включая сам `Chrome`) и в 2.5 раз больше, чем браузер `FireFox`. В Украине и других странах СНГ статистика отличается в сторону `Opera`. И вы говорите "забейте на оперу"?

Comment: "Забивать", увы, пока нельзя, но если так дальше пойдет - сама вымрет. Вечен только IE6...

З.Ы. надо же что-то по теме сказать...

Попробуйте вот этот плагин:
http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html

Comment: @Crasher, я исходил не из статистики, а из того факта, что иностранные заказчики уже давно забили на оперу. Это о чем то да говорит. В России оперой пользуются в основном домохозяйки, школьницы и те, кто уже врос в оперу корнями. Если на нее не забить, то периодически придется ловить баги не только от IE, но от нее родимой. А нам и IE хватает пока. А про мобильную версию тут речи не было. Приведите мне статистику использования десктопной версии в России и сравните с зарубежной.

Comment: @Lucky, те, "кто не знает, что такое браузер", пользуются `IE` и называют браузер "интернетом". Оперой пользуются многие и причины на это более обьективны, чем то, что Вы назвали. Я, например, пользуюсь `Opera` из-за метода скроллинга страниц. Вот ни один браузер не прокручивает страницы так плавно, как опера. 

Более важной причиной может быть потребление оперативной памяти. При трёх десятках открытых страниц, `Opera` использует ~500 Мб ОЗУ, а `Chrome`, в свою очередь, по 50-150 Мб отдельным процессом на каждую вкладку.